# Does anyone know how to draw a vector with sfml in c++?

Tags: c++, draw, sfml

Pretty sure its something like `window.draw(vectorname)`

**Desired behavior**: draw a vector of rectangles, here specifically, 3 white rectangles, 2 spaces, another rectangle and a space

**Error**: (I think) I'm not drawing this correctly

**Code**:

```
window.draw(L0[i]) //the name of the vector is L0
```

**"Relevant Code"**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
//plan how to draw
int x;
vector<RectangleShape> L0; //0 0001101

for (int i=0; i<7; i++) //for which digit were on in L0
{
    x=0;
    if(i==1 or 2 or 3 or 6) //when to print white
    {
        x=x+8;
        RectangleShape white((120,50));
        RectangleShape white(Vector2f(120,50));
        white.setSize(Vector2f(8, 300)); //w and h
        white.setFillColor(Color(255,255,255));
        white.setPosition(x,50)
        L0[i].push_back(white);
    }
    else //when to print a space
    {
        x=x+8;
    }
}
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800,600), "SFML Saves!")
while (window.pollEvent((event))
{
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type==Event::Closed)
        window.close();
}
window.clear();
window.draw(L0[i]);
window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're experiencing? Are you getting an error? Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: You mean like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927780/sfml-2-0-drawing-sprite-vector

Comment: And by relevant code I mean the code we can run ourselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I honestly dont know what sprites are so I'm not sure thats applicable. Its popping up with a lot of errors, maybe the applicable ones are error: 'class sf:: RectangleShape' has no member named 'setsize' or 'push_back'  also no matching function for call to 'sf::RectangleShape::RectangleShape(int) also redeclaration of sf::RectangleShape

Comment: So, basically you have a ton of syntax errors and would like someone to correct them for you?  You declare `white` twice in a row, you should be able to spot that pretty easily.  `if(i==1 or 2 or 3 or 6)` is always true, you should brush up on how logical expressions work in C++.  `L0[i].push_back(white);` should be `L0.push_back(white);` since you're adding items to the vector, and you can't use `L0[i]` when `i` is not in scope at that point.  If you'd like to loop through items, make a loop.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the bad code as pointed out in the comments, you can simply iterate over a vector and draw things.

**C++11**

```
window.clear();
for(const auto& rectangle_shape : L0)
    window.draw(rectangle_shape);
window.display();
```